# Update Status for K8s Custom Resource

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources, operator-sdk

I'm trying to update the status of a custom resource and I'm unable to figure out why its not working..

Here is the `_types.go`:

```golang
// ScoringServerStatus defines the observed state of ScoringServer
type ScoringServerStatus struct {
    // INSERT ADDITIONAL STATUS FIELD - define observed state of cluster
    // Important: Run "make" to regenerate code after modifying this file
    Reason     string             `json:"reason"`
    Message    string             `json:"message"`
    Conditions []metav1.Condition `json:"conditions"`
}

//+kubebuilder:object:root=true
//+kubebuilder:subresource:status

// ScoringServer is the Schema for the scoringservers API
type ScoringServer struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`

    Spec   ScoringServerSpec   `json:"spec,omitempty"`
    Status ScoringServerStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
}
```

I'm trying to set the value of Reason and Message in this status:

```golang
if !isProjectAvailable {
        infoMessage = "Unable to find requested project, can't deploy scoring server"
        log.Log.Info(infoMessage)
        statusUpdate := scoringv1.ScoringServerStatus{Reason: "Unable to verify project in Machinify", Message: infoMessage}
        log.Log.Info(statusUpdate.Reason)
        scoringServer.Status = statusUpdate
        if err := r.Status().Update(ctx, scoringServer); err != nil {
            log.Log.Info(err.Error())
        }
        return ctrl.Result{Requeue: false, RequeueAfter: 0}, nil
    }
```

But nothing changes when I run this. I'm not receiving any errors and if I describe the resource I don't see an updated status...

Comment: I assume that the isProjectAvailable variable is set to false. Could you also include how is the scoringServer struct created or initialized, please?

Answer (score 0):

i just faced the same issue and browsed for answers and somehow your code gave me a hint.

For me this worked fine:

```
err := r.Client.Status().Update(ctx, k8sproj)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("Could not update project id: \n%s\n ", err)
}
```

Notice the `Client()`...

Hope it helps!

Comment: r.Client.Status().Update and r.Status().Update are calling the same function. The latter uses  go embedding.

Answer (score 0):

After you successfully updated the status of your CR you should force to call the `Reconcile` func again by returning a `reconcile.Result` in the following manner:

```golang
if err := r.Status().Update(ctx, scoringServer); err != nil {
  log.Log.Info(err.Error())
}

if err != nil {
  return reconcile.Result{}, err
}
```

Try replace this code fragment:

```golang
return ctrl.Result{Requeue: false, RequeueAfter: 0}, nil
```

with

```golang
if err != nil {
  return reconcile.Result{}, err
}
```

To avoid unnecessary reconciliation loops you can check for changes in the status:

```golang
if !reflect.DeepEqual(oldStatus, newStatus) {
  if err := r.Status().Update(ctx, scoringServer); err != nil {
    log.Log.Info(err.Error())
  }

  if err != nil {
    return reconcile.Result{}, err
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `kubebuilder`, remember to re-apply your CRD yaml file; I just spent 1h debugging this.

```
❯ k apply -f config/crd/bases/<my.domain_type>.yaml
❯ make run
```

That did it for me!